# rename the file name in a folder path using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Below is the bat file:

```
@echo off
set "D=%date%"
echo "%D%"
ren "D:\empty\ EE_DG3-ERROR.txt" "D:\empty\ EE_DG3-ERROR_%D%.txt"
pause
```

I want to append the datetime to the filename.

> **example :** D:\empty\ EE_DG3-ERROR.txt to D:\empty\
>   EE_DG3-ERROR_14oct2013.txt

can you please help me with your suggestions?

Comment: i posted answer. check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** to give a month name

This isn't quite the format you asked for either: But the first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"


if "%mm%"=="01" set "mmm=Jan"
if "%mm%"=="02" set "mmm=Feb"
if "%mm%"=="03" set "mmm=Mar"
if "%mm%"=="04" set "mmm=Apr"
if "%mm%"=="05" set "mmm=May"
if "%mm%"=="06" set "mmm=Jun"
if "%mm%"=="07" set "mmm=Jul"
if "%mm%"=="08" set "mmm=Aug"
if "%mm%"=="09" set "mmm=Sep"
if "%mm%"=="10" set "mmm=Oct"
if "%mm%"=="11" set "mmm=Nov"
if "%mm%"=="12" set "mmm=Dec"

set "fullstamp=%DD%%mmm%%YYYY%"

for %%a in ("D:\empty\EE_DG3-ERROR.txt") do ren "%%~a" "%%~na_%fullstamp%%%~xa"
for %%a in ("D:\empty\plot.log")         do ren "%%~a" "%%~na_%fullstamp%%%~xa"
```

Comment: I'm glad it helps.  Check this item about accepting answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I want to append datetime to a log file .                    example D:\Del\plotserver.log to D:\Del\plotserver_18Oct2013.log. can you please help me. The above scipt is running fine but when i ran it is updating as D:\Del\plotserver.log_18-10-2013         Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Thank you .... If i want to append date to .log files for example plot.log to plot_22Oct2013.log. Is there any chance ? i have tried in multiple ways but in vain. Please help me..

Comment: hi , When I am running the above batch file in a server ,I am getting the error as "the system cannot find the file specified " .Given path is C:\Program Files\Auto\DOC Design Server\Autodesk Client Components\GenApp\dll\plot.log

Comment: Try copying it again, I have changed `"%%a"` to `"%%~a"` in the rename command.  Let me know if it still fails.

Answer (score 3):

```
ren "D:\empty\EE_DG3-ERROR.txt" "EE_DG3-ERROR_%date:/=_%-%time::=_%.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
set dirpath=D:\empty\
ren "%dirpath%EE_DG3-ERROR.txt" EE_DG3-ERROR_14102013.txt
```

Comment: Thank you Manish... when i am giving the date manually it is working fine but the date should be changed automatically when i run this batch file...